# Dynamic row highlighting base on the duplicated values of a column

Tags: excel, spreadsheet

I want to achieve a dynamic row highlighting in Excel as in the picture

[image: Base in the "TitleA" column I want to group it by colors.]

Base in the "TitleA" column (Let's say A column) I want to group it by colors. So, If I sort it I should get something like this:

[image]

I know this could by made using the "Conditional Formatting" option. I have try it without success.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the banding starts in A2, use this formula for your Conditional Formatting:

```
=MOD(SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A2<>$A$1:$A1)*1),2)=0
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer Doug, but I want to "group" them by column A. I just update my question to make it clear.

Comment: Apparently I wasn't paying much attention :).

Answer (score 0):

You could add another column as an indicator (and hide it if necessary). And use this to determine the conditional formatting state.
In the indicator column (assuming your first column is A, and your indicator is in C, beginning at row 2 to allow for a header) put the formula:

```
=IF(A3=A2,C2,IF(C2=1,0,1))
```

This will test the current row, to see if it's the same as the one above, if it is, take the same indicator value (and hence formatting when you set up conditional formatting based on this row), and if it's not the same, be in the opposite state/format.

In this example, you'd use the following formula in your conditional format:

```
=$c3=1
```

and set the format up as desired.